# Failed to build AJAX + PHP request

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, pdo

I am trying to make  AJAX request, but fail to build a right php file.
I am getting such errors in php_error.log . Same php code works fine in usual html file.

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: dbh
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare()
```

included jQuery like this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

AJAX:

```
$(function() {
    $('.openbook').click(function() {
        function testAjax(handleData) {
            $.ajax({
                url:'getopen.php',  
                success:function(data) {
                    handleData(data); 
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
```

testAjax(function(output){
    document.getElementById('#thiswindow').innerHTML = output;
});
            }
        }
    });

getopen.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>   
    <body>
    <?php
        if ( isset( $_SESSION['login'] ) ) {
            $login    = $_SESSION['login'];
            $id=$_SESSION['id'];

            $username="root";
            $password="root";
            $hostname = "localhost";
            $dbname= "kotik";

            function testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password) {
                $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=kotik", $username, $password);
                return $dbh;
            }

            try {
                $dbh = testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password);
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        $title_select_query= $dbh -> prepare("SELECT title FROM books WHERE id = :id ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5,5 ");
        $title_select_query ->execute(array(':id' => $id));
        $title_select_query_result = $title_select_query->fetchColumn(); 
        echo($title_select_query_result);

    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is the issue here? I'v also tried both html+php an php only structure in getopen.php . Can you explain what is the difference?

EDIT 2: AJAX output

EDIT: According to some changes:

```
 <?php 

    session_start();

                                    if ( isset( $_SESSION['login'] ) ) {

  $login    = $_SESSION['login'];
  $id=$_SESSION['id'];

$username="root";
$password="root";
$hostname = "localhost";
$dbname= "kotik";




     function testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password){
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=kotik", $username, $password);
    return $dbh;
}


try {
    $dbh = testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();

}

}




?>

             <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
       <title></title>
       </head>   
       <body>

                                  <?php



                  $title_select_query= $dbh -> prepare("SELECT title FROM books WHERE id = :id ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5,5 ");
    $title_select_query ->execute(array(':id' => $id));
             $title_select_query_result = $title_select_query->fetchColumn(); 
echo($title_select_query_result);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't start session in getopen.php. So you can't check `isset( $_SESSION['login'] )`. And so you don't initialize `$dbh` variable.

Try to add `session_start();` to getopen.php

Comment: PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Comment: now no errors, but data is still now shown
html is right, I'v checked

Comment: And what is with variable $_SESSION['login']. Is it defined earlier?

Comment: at least same code works fine in the index.php - condition must be right

Comment: Replace `if ( isset( $_SESSION['login'] ) ) {` with `if (1) {` and check it. Still PHP warnings and errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75838/discussion-between-vinand-and-2kai).

Answer (score 2):

you have your PDO connection assigned to the $dbh variable inside an if conditional.  you then drop out of the if and still use the $dbh variable in the rest of the code.  It's looking a lot like you are not meeting the condition of your if statement and as such are never assigning $dbh before trying to use it.

Comment: MuppetGrinder is correct. The variables $dbh, $username, $hostname, $password and $dbname are only being defined if the $_SESSION['login'] variable exists and I don't see that being created in your code. If that session variable doesn't exist, the other variables can not be used outside of the conditional statement unless they are defined outside of the condition